# Is there any way to create custom locale in Java?

Tags: calendar, locale, vaadin

I am using Vaadin calendar and want to change month, weeks to my own language (Mongolian). Java doesn't have Mongolian locale so I need to create custom locale.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html

Comment: i18n wouldn't suit on  my case. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The valid way to create Mongolian `Locale` is to use its constructor:

```
new Locale("mon", "MN")
```

Arguments of the constructor are [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639_macrolanguage) and [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) codes of Mongolian language and country.

Note, that it doesn't mean that Vaadin must implement Mongolian version of its Calendar widget. So you still may see English calendar unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, Vaadin calendar doesn't implement Mongolian locale.

Comment: That's true but it doesn't change the fact that the answer given is correct. Its a good practice to mark the correct answer.